Playwright Test Timeout: Exceeded While Setting Up "mockServiceWorker" (MSW)
I'm using Playwright with a custom fixture setup to initialize a MockServiceWorker to intercept network requests for testing. However, I’m encountering the following timeout error in our e2e tests, which are triggered by a pull request (PR) and run in an Azure environment:
Test timeout of 100000ms exceeded while setting up "mockServiceWorker".

Here's how the fixture is set up in the baseTest.extend configuration:

mockServiceWorker: [
  async ({ page }, use): Promise<void> => {
    if (appSettings.MockService.useMockServiceWorker) {
      const server = await createWorker(page, handlers); // initializes mock service worker
      await use(server);
    }
  },
  {
    scope: 'test',
    auto: true,
  },
],

createWorker is a native method in playwright-msw lib.
Local Behavior: Tests pass locally without timeouts, ie the worker is created and injected successfully
Additional Notes: The handlers file is currently empty, so it shouldn’t be causing any specific delays.
Setting auto: true for mockServiceWorker to preload it.
Adjusting timeouts in test.setTimeout and playwright.config.ts, though I don't believe this is purely a time-related issue, so extending the timeout doesn't seem like the right solution here.
my goal is to make our e2e affected tests run with msw, intercepting calls to test our FE changes.
Any insights or advice on how to resolve or troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!
